# Get sessionId/ serverUrl with login webservice soapUI

Tags: webservices, soap, enterprise-wsdl

By using  "Generate Enterprise WSDL " I got the below login webservice for my salesforce org.

### Login webservice

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:LoginScopeHeader>
         <urn:organizationId>?</urn:organizationId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:portalId>?</urn:portalId>
      </urn:LoginScopeHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>enter preformatted text here
      <urn:login>
         <urn:username>username</urn:username>
         <urn:password>"mypassword+securitytoken"</urn:password>
      </urn:login>
   </soapenv:Body>


</soapenv:Envelope>
```

After running this in SOAP UI, I did not get the sessionId/ serverUrl.
The error I got as below:

### Output

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>INVALID_LOGIN</faultcode>
         <faultstring>INVALID_LOGIN: malformed id: organizationId '?'</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <sf:LoginFault xsi:type="sf:LoginFault">
               <sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_LOGIN</sf:exceptionCode>
               <sf:exceptionMessage>malformed id: organizationId '?'</sf:exceptionMessage>
            </sf:LoginFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you once remove inside the header and test it

Comment: Can you remove inside the header like below: <urn:LoginScopeHeader>
         <urn:organizationId>?</urn:organizationId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:portalId>?</urn:portalId>
      </urn:LoginScopeHeader>

Comment: Thanks @Nikitha . After removing the header I got the sessionId and session url.

Comment: Ok fine Dominic...

Answer (score 1):

You don't  need to define the [`<urn:LoginScopeHeader>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_loginscopeheader.htm) as part of the login API call unless you are authenticating a Self-Service user against a specific org and portal. If that isn't the case you can safely omit that header.